# How to find all issues in which a comic character appeared?

Tags: marvel

If you search for the comics in which a character appears on comicvine or marvelwiki, you mostly get links to a series (like 'The Avengers United', etc). How can we find out the exact issues in which that character appears

Comment: I believe [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/YBxeD.png) is the button you want

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about science-fiction works, but requesting tool or resource recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

#### The only definitive way to be certain a character appeared in a book: Read them. Wikis are filled with minor inaccuracies. If your life depends on knowing which comics a hero appears in, then do the research yourself. For casual use, most wikis will promote the issues a character appears depending on the depth of that site's interest in a character's history.

- Most online publications will only list the most famous appearances: first appearance, costume changes, major power shifts, major changes in writers, definitive story arcs, deaths or extended periods of inactivity.
- Any online publication which is openly sourced is subject to human error, since there is no one checking to ensure the accuracy of the work, except other volunteers. To give credit where credit is due, sites such as the Marvel Wikia, ComicVine and Wikipedia are decent online references but hardly perfect. As far as comics are concerned, no resource can be considered perfect.
- Publications such as the [**Overstreet Comics Price Guide**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1603601376) might help, since they make their living selling comics and character appearances to the highest bidder.

[image]

> The Overstreet Comic Book Price Guide (or Official Overstreet Comic Book Price Guide) is an annually published comic book price guide widely considered the primary authority on the subject of American comic book grading and pricing in the hobby/industry. Many observers tie in the growth of the direct market distribution system and comic book specialty shops to the general acceptance of Overstreet's annual guide as a standardized inventory and pricing system.
>
> Begun in 1970 by Robert M. Overstreet as a guide for fellow fans of Golden Age and Silver Age comics, the Overstreet guide has expanded to cover virtually the entire history of the American comics publication as far back as the Victorian Age and Platinum Age.